# MySQL 5.7 statistics - Change db

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a MySQL 5.7 database. I was looking in statistics in server status that shows type of queries / commands / tasks executed in the database. It shows that the query command "change db" by far was the most frequent one.

[image]

What does the "change db" value mean in Server > Status > Statistics? I only have one database (except system databases) why is the query running so often, almost twice select?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400434/why-are-change-db-and-set-option-so-high-in-the-mysql-query-stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using a 3rd party package.  And it probably does a "USE" at the beginning of every connection, possibly much more often.

The frequency of `SHOW` commands also smells like a sloppy 3rd package that can't remember what it is working with.

Another possibility is a monitoring package.  However, I would expect to see even more `SHOWs`.

One way to track things down is to turn on the "general log" for a short while, then look at that log to see which "user" is doing what.